# Carousal view bind auto duration value - Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my xamarin.forms app, I am using Cardview's [link](https://github.com/AndreiMisiukevich/CardView) cubeview. The cubeview is similar to carousal with a property called auto sliding. We can set the duration and it will auto slide after that time. In this cube view I am using two different templates. One for showing image and another one for video. I can show these two different views by using data template selector. Everything works fine.

Now, since the auto slide property is hard coded, even if the video or image fully loaded(I am fetching them from URL.) the view will get slided. How can bind or reference the auto duration value to the loading property of Image and video?

For Image view I am using `FFImageloading`

For Video view I am using `Rox.Xamarin.Video`

In summarise, if the image is loaded, I want to make the auto slide value to `7 seconds` and if it is video I want the autoslide duration needs to be the duration of video. How can I do that? Any help is apprecited.

**My cube view**

```
   <cards:CubeView
            x:Name="StatusCarousal" 
            IsClippedToBounds="True"

            SlideShowDuration="7000"   // This value needs to be bind according to template
    
            IsVerticalSwipeEnabled="True"
            ItemSwiped="StatusCarousal_ItemSwiped"
            PropertyChanged="StatusCarousal_PropertyChanged"
            ItemsSource="{Binding}"                                           
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource personDataTemplateSelector}"          
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  >
                </cards:CubeView>
```

**Data Templates**

```
  <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="Page1Template" >
                    <ffimageloading:CachedImage Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                             x:Name="StoryImage"
                             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                             Source="{Binding Image}"    
                             Aspect="AspectFill"
                             Success="CachedImage_Success"
                             FileWriteFinished="CachedImage_FileWriteFinished"
                             DownsampleToViewSize="true"
                             DownloadStarted="CachedImage_DownloadStarted"
                               >
                                </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="Page2Template">
                 <rox:VideoView    Source="{Binding VideoURl}" AutoPlay="True" FullScreen="True"                                                  
                                                  Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"                                                                                                                   
                                                  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"                                           
                                        >
                                </rox:VideoView>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
            <local:PersonDataTemplateSelector x:Key="personDataTemplateSelector"
            Page1="{StaticResource  Page1Template}"
            Page2="{StaticResource  Page2Template}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
```

**Model class**

```
public partial class InnerStoreisData : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public ImageSource profileImage { get; set; }
        public string VideoURl { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public int Type { get; set; }
    
    }
```

**Template selector**

```
public class PersonDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate Page1 { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate Page2 { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        switch (((InnerStoreisData)item).Type)
        {
            case 0:
                return Page1;
            case 1:
                return Page2;           
            default:
                return Page1;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AutoDuration)) after you change it from the ViewModel ?

Comment: @RedZ Actually No. But how can I referance two diffrent property to the duration in this case?

Comment: add one more property to your model let say the name of property is IsVideo of type bool, use the reference of this property to determine if its video or image and place a converter in SlideShowDuration which would return the duration after checking bool value and if u want to make it more easy check the TypeOf your content

Comment: @RonakShethia Thanks for reply. Can we refer the item inside data template to the carousal property?

Comment: yes we can, you need to give the source reference in the binding context https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/binding-path go through this article

Comment: @RonakShethia Hi, May I ask one more thing. I updated the question with my model class and template selctor. I have this property "Type" which will used to show image and video. How can I refer this property to my "slideshowduration' ?

Comment: @RonakShethia like {{Binding Source={x:Reference Type}}}?

Comment: SlideShowDuration="{Binding Source={x:Reference yourListName}, Path=SelectedItem,Converter={StaticResource DurationConverter}}"

Comment: the DurationConveter would Receive model of first element in the value, retrieve the value of duration from your model and use if condition to check it if the value is 0 return 0 or else return the duration

Comment: @RonakShethia Bro I am unable to create the converter. Can you help me on that part?

Comment: @RonakShethia because the duration of video is only get after loading the video on player

Comment: get in touch with me on linkedin : ronak.shethia@gmail.com